# No permissions to send email from Excel-VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I used to send email from VBA from an Excel Workbook. This worked correct.
Now I have a new PC and tried to run the same code. And I get a permission error. 
I have checked, re-checked and double checked with my old PC, but I can't find any difference in settings. Not in Excel, nor in Outlook. 
Here is the mail I get when I try to send the mail (I just masked my email address with xxx@yyy,.nl).

Ntired everyting … nothing works …

```
Sender = "<Support> support@xxx.com"

Set objMail = objOl.CreateItem(0)
With objMail
    .Sentonbehalfofname = Sender
    .Subject = qrySubj
    .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>" & Text & "</BODY></HTML>"
    .DeleteAfterSubmit = False
    .To = Receiver
    .Send
End With
```

On my old PC the mail is sent. On my new PC i get:

Uw bericht heeft enkele of alle geadresseerden niet bereikt.

```
  Onderwerp:    Dagelijkse rapportage mails
  Verzonden:    13-8-2019 07:54
```

De volgende geadresseerde(n) zijn niet bereikt:

```
  'xxx@yyy.nl' op 13-8-2019 07:54
        Dit bericht is niet verzonden. U bent niet gemachtigd om het bericht namens de opgegeven gebruiker te verzenden.
```

---

Diagnostische gegevens voor beheerders:

---

Fout is [0x80070005-0x000004dc-0x00000524].

Exchange-antwoordheaders:
    request-id: 09cc6cb4-af3f-4613-ac6a-4bb18046bd0e
    X-ServerApplication: Exchange/15.20.2157.000
    X-FEServer: AM0PR02CA0053
    X-BEServer: AM0PR08MB4387
    X-CalculatedBETarget: AM0PR08MB4387.eurprd08.prod.outlook.com
    X-RequestId: {F6762D9D-3507-476D-93ED-008D1A05C6A3}:108
    X-ClientInfo: {17B3EEB2-65A2-4317-8132-4E5BAD253A55}:241960014
    X-ElapsedTime: 1430
    X-BackEndHttpStatus: 200
    X-ResponseCode: 0
    X-DiagInfo: AM0PR08MB4387
    X-RequestType: Execute

---

Overzicht van externe bewerkingen:

```
0: ropWriteStream (45) Verwerkt(1) Voltooid(0)
    Resultaat van externe bewerkingen: 0
    Reactiecodes: 0
1: ropRelease (1) Verwerkt(1) Voltooid(0)
    Resultaat van externe bewerkingen: 0
    Reactiecodes: 0
2: ropSetProps (10) Verwerkt(1) Voltooid(0)
    Resultaat van externe bewerkingen: 0
    Reactiecodes: 0
3: ropFlushRecipients (14) Verwerkt(1) Voltooid(0)
    Resultaat van externe bewerkingen: 0
    Reactiecodes: 0
4: ropSetProps (10) Verwerkt(1) Voltooid(0)
    Resultaat van externe bewerkingen: 0
    Reactiecodes: 0
5: ropTransportSend (74) Verwerkt(1) Voltooid(0)
    Resultaat van externe bewerkingen: 0
    Reactiecodes: 1244
```

---

Uitzonderingen bij reacties:

Index van externe bewerkingen: 5
Gekoppelde externe bewerkingen: ropTransportSend (74)
Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.SendAsDeniedException: Can't transport send message. ---> Microsoft.Mapi.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied: MapiExceptionSendAsDenied: Unable to transport send message. (hr=0x80070005, ec=1244)
Diagnostic context:
    Lid: 35250
    Lid: 36674   dwParam: 0xA
    Lid: 61250   dwParam: 0x0
    Lid: 45378   dwParam: 0x2
    Lid: 44866   dwParam: 0x46C
    Lid: 36674   dwParam: 0xE
    Lid: 61250   dwParam: 0x0
    Lid: 45378   dwParam: 0x471
    Lid: 44866   dwParam: 0x236
    Lid: 55847   EMSMDBPOOL.EcPoolSessionDoRpc called [length=1049]
    Lid: 43559   EMSMDBPOOL.EcPoolSessionDoRpc returned [ec=0x0][length=148][latency=0]
    Lid: 52176   ClientVersion: 15.20.2157.0
    Lid: 50032   ServerVersion: 15.20.2157.6000
    Lid: 35180
    Lid: 23226   --- ROP Parse Start ---
    Lid: 27962   ROP: ropSetProps [10]
    Lid: 27962   ROP: ropFlushRecipients [14]
    Lid: 31418   --- ROP Parse Done ---
    Lid: 35250
    Lid: 36674   dwParam: 0xA
    Lid: 61250   dwParam: 0x0
    Lid: 45378   dwParam: 0x2
    Lid: 44866   dwParam: 0x46
    Lid: 36674   dwParam: 0x4A
    Lid: 61250   dwParam: 0x0
    Lid: 45378   dwParam: 0x4B
    Lid: 44866   dwParam: 0x0
    Lid: 55847   EMSMDBPOOL.EcPoolSessionDoRpc called [length=172]
    Lid: 43559   EMSMDBPOOL.EcPoolSessionDoRpc returned [ec=0x0][length=368][latency=0]
    Lid: 52176   ClientVersion: 15.20.2157.0
    Lid: 50032   ServerVersion: 15.20.2157.6000
    Lid: 35180
    Lid: 23226   --- ROP Parse Start ---
    Lid: 27962   ROP: ropSetProps [10]
    Lid: 27962   ROP: ropTransportSend [74]
    Lid: 17082   ROP Error: 0x4DC
    Lid: 44949
    Lid: 21921   StoreEc: 0x4DC
    Lid: 27962   ROP: ropExtendedError [250]
    Lid: 1494    ---- Remote Context Beg ----
    Lid: 38698
    Lid: 37692
    Lid: 37948
    Lid: 33852   dwParam: 0x0        Msg: SMTP
    Lid: 56248   StoreEc: 0x4DC
    Lid: 40748   qdwParam: 0xB01000000000001 
    Lid: 57132   qdwParam: 0x0
    Lid: 63016   dwParam: 0x4A
    Lid: 39640   StoreEc: 0x4DC
    Lid: 45434   Guid: 00011788-362d-8c85-0000-000000000000
    Lid: 10786   dwParam: 0x0        Msg: 15.20.2157.000:AM0PR08MB4387:74f6b60d-ca04-46c4-80ff-8a31bf2a4ef7
    Lid: 1750    ---- Remote Context End ----
    Lid: 31418   --- ROP Parse Done ---
    Lid: 22753
    Lid: 21817   ROP Failure: 0x4DC
    Lid: 59285
    Lid: 46997   StoreEc: 0x4DC
   at Microsoft.Mapi.MapiExceptionHelper.ThrowIfError(String message, Int32 hresult, IExInterface iUnknown, Exception innerException, MapiStore mapiStore)
   at Microsoft.Mapi.MapiBase.ThrowIfError(String message, Int32 hr)
   at Microsoft.Mapi.MapiMessage.TransportSendMessage(PropValue[]& propsToReturn)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.MapiAccessor.TransportSendMessage(Object mapiObject, ExTimeZone timezone, PropertyDefinition[]& propertyDefinitions, Object[]& propertyValues)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.MapiAccessor.TransportSendMessage(Object mapiObject, ExTimeZone timezone, PropertyDefinition[]& propertyDefinitions, Object[]& propertyValues)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.CoreItem.TransportSend(PropertyDefinition[]& properties, Object[]& values)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.RpcClientAccess.Handler.Message.TransportSend()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.RpcClientAccess.Handler.RopHandler.<>c__DisplayClass154_0.b__0()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.RpcClientAccess.Handler.ExceptionTranslator.TryExecuteCatchAndTranslateExceptions[TResult](Func`1 protectedCode, Func`2 errorCodeExtractor, Boolean noThrow, TResult& result, Exception& exception, ErrorCode& errorCode)

Transportverzending is mislukt: foutopsomming(25), HResult(0x00000000), EC(1244).
Transportverzending is mislukt: foutopsomming(22), HResult(0x00000000), EC(1244).
Berichtverzending is mislukt: bericht-id(4), foutopsomming(13), HResult(0x80070005), EC(1244).

Comment: Please translate your question completely to english. Also set your language settings such, that the error stack can be also read in english, thanks

Comment: How to do that? No idea how to change language settings. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

That means you (the current profile user) cannot send on behalf of the specified user. Try to comment out the line setting the `SentoObehalfOfName` property and see if the message goes through.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did, but then the message gets sent from my hotmail-account (Exchange) rather the my company account (xxx@bid72.com), even if I have my company account set as default account.

Comment: However, you put me in the right direction. I then removed my Hotmail account. I tried again and it worked fine. I added my Hotmail account and it still working fine. You made my day. Thanks a lot.

Comment: That is because Hotmail is no longer your default account. SentoObehalfOfName  can only be set to a name from the same Exchange org where the message is created.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You helped me already greatly through a different site!!